# How to create login form using oracle database?

Tags: php, oracle

Thanks in advance. 
I'm having trouble creating login form with oracle database actually I have created successful connection but problem with login form connectivity

```
    $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr', 'localhost/XE', 'AL32UTF8');
    session_start();

    $myusername = isset($_POST['username']);
    $mypassword = isset($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM VTP_admin WHERE username='".$myusername."' and password='".$mypassword."'  ";
    $vtpid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

    $result = oci_execute($vtpid);

    $count=oci_num_rows($vtpid);
    echo ($count);

    if($count==1){
        $_SESSION["username"];
        $_SESSION["password"];

        header("localhost/ERP/dashboard.php");
    }
    else{
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
    }
```

Comment: can you please update what you tried..

Comment: This code I have done.

Comment: you should create methods and use PDO

Comment: What value is stored in $conn , because you haven't include database configuration.

Comment: database connectivity is stored in $conn

Comment: @sid :     $query = "SELECT * FROM VTP_admin WHERE username='".$myusername."' and password='".$mypassword."'  ";
having extra space at the end ....can you check it once by removing it

Comment: @kranthi Still it is not working.

Comment: @sid print query and check it by running in oracle..

Comment: @sid , in your page you didn't mention the database configuration , or you must include config file.

Comment: @ArchanaPalani I have done so but not included here.

Comment: @sid please post your complete code

Comment: @sid , i don't see any syntax error in the code , try to echo the query and execute directly in database.

Answer (score 1):

Finally achieved this task it might help some buddy. If you have questions feel free to ask.

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        global $conn;
        $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr', 'localhost/XE', 'AL32UTF8');
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $user = $_POST['username'];
            $pass = $_POST['password'];
            $s = oci_parse($conn, "select username,password from vtp_admin where username='$user' and password='$pass'");       
            oci_execute($s);
            $row = oci_fetch_all($s, $res);
            if($row){
                    $_SESSION['user']=$user;
                    $_SESSION['time_start_login'] = time();
                    header("location: dashboard.php");
            }else{

                echo "wrong password or username";
            }
        }



     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <?php
    
    $conn = oci_connect('hr', 'hr', 'localhost/XE', 'AL32UTF8');
    session_start();
    
    // Check if POST variables are set and retrieve their values
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $myusername = $_POST['username'];
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $mypassword = $_POST['password'];
    }
    
    // Use bind variables in the SQL query to prevent SQL injection attacks
    $query = "SELECT * FROM VTP_admin WHERE username=:myusername and password=:mypassword";
    $vtpid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_bind_by_name($vtpid, ":myusername", $myusername);
    oci_bind_by_name($vtpid, ":mypassword", $mypassword);
    
    $result = oci_execute($vtpid);
    
    $count = oci_num_rows($vtpid);
    echo ($count);
    
    if ($count == 1) {
        // Assign values to session variables
        $_SESSION["username"] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION["password"] = $mypassword;
    
        // Use the "Location" header to redirect to the dashboard.php page
        header("Location: http://localhost/ERP/dashboard.php");
        exit; // Always exit after a header() redirect
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
    }
    
        ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?PHP

require_once 'db_connect.php';
session_start();

$user = $_POST['USER_NAME'];
$pass = $_POST['PASSWORD'];
$s = oci_parse($con, "select USER_NAME,PASSWORD from usermst where USER_NAME='$user' and PASSWORD='$pass'");       
oci_execute($s);
$row = oci_fetch_all($s, $RESULT);
$RESULT = array();
if($row){
    $_SESSION['USER_NAME']=$user;
    $_SESSION['time_start_login'] = time();
    $RESULT['message']="Login Successfully"; 
}else{
    //$RESULT['message']="Warning!";
    $RESULT['message']="Username or password is incorrect.";
}
$r = array($RESULT);
echo json_encode($r);
```